# Compile TypeScript to multiple targets

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, tsconfig

I want to compile Typescript files to multiple targets like to ES5 and ES6 both. I have the following example directory:

**ES5**

**ES6**

**test.ts**

**tsconfig.json**

So when I run the compiler I want it to compile test.ts as ES5 to the ES5 folder and as ES6 to the ES6 folder. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: It's certainly possible, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A simple solution would be to create two `tsconfig.json` files with the different targets and output directories.

**tsconfig-es5.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "outDir": "./ES5",
    // Additional configuration like module type etc.
}
```

**tsconfig-es6.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "outDir": "./ES6",
    // Additional configuration like module type etc.
}
```

Then create a build script that concatenates the building, e.g. for Windows:

`tsc --project ./tsconfig-es5.json && tsc --project ./tsconfig-es6.json`

The alternative would be to have one tsconfig.json and directly specify the `target` and `outDir` parameters in the build script (see [Compiler Options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)).